# Which jtopen jar to be used

Tags: jdbc, db2-400

I am using DB2 i-series DB on AS400 and am unable to connect.

Below are details:
Platform: As400 i-series

DB: Db2 i-series

JDBC driver used: jt400-9.4-jt400_jdk8.jar

Tool Used: DB2 Visualizer (10.0.25)

Can anybody suggest if I am using the correct JDBC driver version or I should be using something different.

Error:
An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Long Message:
The application requester cannot establish the connection. (XXXXXXX)

Details:
   Type: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException
   Error Code: -99999
   SQL State: 08001

Comment: Do you mean "DB2 Visualizer" or do you mean "DB Visualizer"? I don't think `jt400-9.4-jt400_jdk8.jar` is a JDBC driver. It's [this toolbox](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/), which contains bundled JDBC tools.  If you are using DB Visualizer, try this JAR: `db2jcc4.jar`. See [here](https://www.dbvis.com/features/db2-luw-database-drivers/) for details. And note: "_This driver is co-packaged with DbVisualizer_."

Comment: Since the message comes typically from jt400 jdbc driver I think it's a good one. To be sure you can download jtopen from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jt400 and extract jt400.jar

Comment: Your problem is probably somewhere else. Could be the server is down, or you are not connecting to what you think it is, but probably you have a firewall that forbids port 446 in between

Comment: port number 446 is wrong, check there https://javadoc.midrange.com/ports.php